# Owned Azure Subscription not showing in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to setup an CICD from our Azure Devops to the Azure Subscription owned by our Client.
But the subscription is not appearing in the list of Azure Subscriptions even if I already have Owner level of role:

My CICD Subscription List Available:
[image]

The Subscription where I want to deploy:
[image]

My current role to our Client Active Directory:
[image]

**Also note that I am a Member of their Active Directory not just a Guest.**

I also checked this article but no luck:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#the-user-has-only-guest-permission-in-the-directory

Comment: Update: the problem is not with the roles and permissions, for some reason AAD with MFA enables somehow prevents smooth integration with Azure DevOps, on my case i disabled deleted my MFA options then tried to add the subscription again via Azure Pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the roles and permissions, for some reason AAD with MFA enables somehow prevents smooth integration with Azure DevOps, on my case i disabled deleted my MFA options then tried to add the subscription again via Azure Pipeline.

Comment: I was able to keep MFA switched on (which is much safer) - I logged out of Azure Portal and Azure Devops, then I closed and reopened my browser and logged into Azure Devops. I could see my subscriptions!

Answer (score 2):

[Some subscriptions are missing from the list of subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#some-subscriptions-are-missing-from-the-list-of-subscriptions):

To fix this issue you will need to modify the supported account types and who can use your application. To do so, follow the steps below:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. If you have access to multiple tenants, use the **Directory + subscription** filter in the top menu to select the tenant in which you want to register an application.
3. Search for and select **Azure Active Directory**.
4. Under **Manage**, select **App registrations**.
5. Select you application from the list of registered applications.
6. Under **Essentials**, select **Supported account types**.
7. Under **Supported account types**, *Who can use this application or access this API?* select **Accounts in any organizational directory**.
8. Select **Save**.